# Backbone Collections - fetch() ,success callback not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am coding in Backbone Js and this is my code :

```
var Router, UserList, Users, router, userList;

    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
      return options.url = "http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com" + options.url;
    });

    Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: '/users'
    });

    UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#app',
      render: function() {
        var users;
        users = new Users();
        return users.fetch({
          success: function() {
            return console.log("Please log something!! ");
          }
        });
      }
    });

    userList = new UserList();

    Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: {
        '': 'home'
      },
      home: function() {
        console.log('Welcome home my friend!!');
        return userList.render();
      }
    });

    router = new Router();

    Backbone.history.start();
```

But the success callback in the collection.fetch() is not working. It is not logging anything!

Here is the JsFiddle : jsfiddle.net/9DjPY/1

Please help me!

Comment: Any chance an `error` callback is trying to fire instead?

Comment: Does collection send request to server, because it think they send to unreachable place

Comment: Yes I am getting the data back! I checked the console. There is no error. I even tried the error callback.. Still nothing,

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle demo, it can help with debug)))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9DjPY/1/

Comment: Yes am getting the same issue here, Am getting the data fine from the server, and the data is in correct format, bus success function never called here

Comment: I am able to get an error when I pass an error callback in your JSFiddle. I would look into that more.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change AJAX implementation, Backbone way is to extend their methods Backbone.ajax instead of changing jQuery

View should return itself instead of collection instance.
Also, instead of listening to success, you should probably listen to add or reset.

```
var Router, UserList, Users, router, userList,
    oldSync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.ajax = function(options) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    options || (options = {});
    if (options.url) {
        options.url = (/^https?/.test(options.url) ? '' : 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com') + options.url;
    }
    return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, [options].concat(args));
};
Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/users'
});

UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',
  initialize: function () {
      this.collection = new Users();
  },
  render: function() {
      this.collection.fetch({
          success: function () { console.log('Users', arguments) }
      });
      return this;
  }
});

userList = new UserList();

Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'home'
  },
  home: function() {
    console.log('Welcome home my friend!!');
    return userList.render();
  }
});

router = new Router();

Backbone.history.start();
```

Here is a working example - http://jsfiddle.net/hypernurb/9DjPY/5/.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem on your server side, try following where i have added error option in fetch:

```
UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',
  render: function() {
    var users;
    users = new Users();
    return users.fetch({
      success: function() {
        return console.log("Please log something!! ");
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log(arguments);
        return console.log("Error log something!! ");
      }
    });
  }
});
```